# Converting php password hash to original value is that possible?

Tags: php

I am using code

```
$password1 = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

and trying to insert `$encrypt` to database.

I want to find out a way to decrypt them. Is that possible?? How?? Sorry if I am wrong.

Comment: **NO. that's the whole point**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't revert back to the original values. If you are using any encryption algorithm. Otherwise, Hackers would blow up your sites in seconds. The sole purpose of using hashing algorithms is to save and encrypt data using a very large value. There are many algorithms which do encryption some of them are md1 and sha1. Many websites offer that they can retrieve original value but not in an instant. It requires a brute force to retrieve original passwords.

Comment: I am simply trying to view all username and passwords in admin dashboard.

Comment: @MuraliManoj there is only one person who should know a users password, and it's not you

Comment: your answer makes no sense, you seem to suggest if it was reversible that would make you more hackable, which is simply not the case.

Comment: https://culttt.com/2013/01/21/why-do-you-need-to-salt-and-hash-passwords/

Comment: "And there you have it, a simple and secure way to store your user’s passwords. Storing passwords shouldn’t be difficult and should be a problem you can solve once. However, if you don’t do it properly, you could face a serious backlash should your database ever be compromised." so ? nothing there about making you more vunrable to being hacked.

Comment: yes? can you write full sentences please.  I dont understand your point.

Comment: the full sentence is "However, if you don’t do it properly, you could face a serious backlash should your database ever be compromised." which seems self explanatory? and has nothing to do with making you more hackable in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

No, and you're **not supposed to be able to do it at all**.

Hashing is, by design, supposed to be irreversible. That is the design goal. If you can reverse a hashing result of an algorithm, the algorithm is faulty and should be avoided.

### Brute Force Cracking

There is a way to guess the password by brute force.

You can:

1. make a list of all the possible password combinations you can imagine. Then,
2. you can make a hash, with the same algorithm you used, of each and
   every one of them.
3. If one of them matches the hash of your password,
   there you have it.

Someone has already made tools for this purpose, you may try them. For example:

- https://github.com/BREAKTEAM/Debcrypt

Don't be too hopeful. If the password you're cracking is not in the list of "all the possible password combinations you can imagine", then you won't be able to get it this way.

### How hashed password are usually used

You'd usually compare the hash of the login user's password input with your database password hash. The same string going through the same hashing process would always give you the same result.

For example,

```php
$user = my_get_user($_POST['username']);
if ($user === null) {
  // login failed
  // ...
} else if (!password_verify($_POST['password'], $user->password)) {
  // login failed
  // ...
} else {
  // login success
  // ...
}
```

As an **honest** service provider, you're **not supposed** to know your user actual password. And hashing is a way to ensure you can check users' password without knowing them at all.

Answer (score -2):

Depends on your website program system platform. For some sites, its a combination of your password and another variable sometimes called **"salt"** with a secret algorithm, and really depends on the platform used, it could vary. If you create your own program you could probably hash and dehash your own password just to test your code, then you can reverse the process but it is very easy to decrypt. Some other use a **secret key** combined with your hash, and there are other ways to achieve that, but never directly.

MD5 Hash Generator http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php

MD5 Hash Decryption https://www.md5online.org/md5-decrypt.html

I haven´t seen a smart platform program to use the simple **hash** / **decrypt hash** algorithm as a password validation procedure. But you could write your own code for testing purposes only.